# How to really clean the property from System class?

Tags: java

I am trying to do a request on a REST service on two different web servers. On both servers it is necessary to present a keyStore, obviously they are different keyStores. Running the code below I am having successful only in the first request (for the test environment), but when I do the second request (for the staging environment), the request presents the first keyStore, in this case testKeyStore.jks.

I tried to clear the keyStore property of the System class and set a new value. In println it is displayed as if the property was changed, but when I see the log on the staging server, the ***testKeyStore*** was presented, not the ***stagingKeyStore***.

If I change de order, first STAGING and then TEST, in *doStaff()* method, the second request fail because the stagingKeyStore is present in the test-server.

Is there some solution to solve this problem?

```
public void doStaff() {
    callServer("TEST");
    callServer("STAGING");
}

private void callServer(String enviroment) {
    String url = "";
    if ("TEST".equalsIgnoreCase(enviroment))
        url = "https://test-server/dostaff";
    else if("STAGING".equalsIgnoreCase(enviroment))
        url = "https://staging-server/dostaff";

    try {
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
        System.out.println(enviroment + " -> " + System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
        
        if ("TEST".equalsIgnoreCase(enviroment)) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\temp\\testKeyStore.jks");
        } else if("STAGING".equalsIgnoreCase(enviroment)) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\temp\\stagingKeyStore.jks");
        }
        System.out.println(enviroment + " -> " + System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
        
        //...
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of these calls? You usually don't store test logic within your production code. Also, you can combine the two keystores into one.

Comment: It also looks like you're reinventing capabilities that are provided by tools like Spring Boot and Micronaut.

Comment: @maio290 I need these calls to compare the result. It is not a productive enviroment.
I tryed to put both key in the same keystore, but it didn't work.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I don't know about Micronaut, this solution I'm using Spring Boot.

Comment: Spring Boot provides _complete_ management for all of this. You're looking for "Spring profiles" and [this list of properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html), specifically the ones that talk about trust and key stores.